# LDAP Java attribute maxpwdAge returns -864000000000

Tags: java, ldap

In `Java`, I tried to read the attribute `maxpwdAge`, and in `LDAP`, this attribute is defined as `180 days`, but in my Java API returns `-864000000000`.

Do you know if this issue is related to the permissions in `LDAP`? How can I fix it?

Regards.

Comment: According to [MSDN, maxpwdAge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220201.aspx) is _period of time expressed in a negative number of 100-nanosecond time slices_. So your value is one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a method for converting ldap time period to days count:

```
public static Long ldapTimePeriodToDays(String ldapPeriod) {
    Long ldapPeriodLong = Long.parseLong(ldapPeriod);

    long days = Math.abs(ldapPeriodLong
            / 10_000    //100-nanosecond time slices to milliseconds
            / 1000      //to seconds
            / 60        //to minutes
            / 60        //to hours
            / 24        //to days
    );

    return days;
}
```